# Insert image src into Javascript Array by Class Name

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a JavaScript that will randomize images on page refresh. I'm not really familiar with JS so I've been having a bit of trouble.

I've succeeded in building a successful program by hard coding the image url sources into the JS array, but this is not a possibility for what I am coding this for because the user will dictate what set of images will display. The user will not have access to the JS. So the array would get the image sources from the html. What I've been trying to do is use "getElementByClassName" and insert into the array by for loop. But it doesn't seem to be working. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this as well, so feel free to enlighten me.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!-- Images to put into JS Array -->
<img class="header" src="/image1.jpg" style="display: none;" />
<img class="header" src="/image2.jpg" style="display: none;" />
<img class="header" src="/image3.jpg" style="display: none;" />

<!-- Image placeholder -->
<img src="/image1.jpg" id="rotate" />
```

And the JavaScript in a separate document:

```
// Javascript code
window.onload = chooseHeader;

var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("header");
var headers = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    headers.push(imgs[i].src);
}


function chooseHeader() {
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * headers.length));
    document.getElementById("rotate").src = headers[rand];
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Do not forget to mark and upvote for the answer that resolved your query.

Comment: I did try to upvote it, but it says I need to have 15+ reputation. I just joined the site to ask this question, so I don’t have many reputations yet :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is probably running before the DOM has loaded.

You don't actually need an `Array` for this, and since `getElementsByClassName` returns a "live list", you can fetch the images before they exist, and they'll appear when they're loaded in the document.

So if that's the case, a solution is to get the `src` directly from `imgs`.

```js
window.onload = chooseHeader;

// live list
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("header");

function chooseHeader() {
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgs.length));
    document.getElementById("rotate").src = imgs[rand].src;
}
```

```html
<img class=header src="https://dummyimage.com/50/f00/fff.jpg">
<img class=header src="https://dummyimage.com/50/0f0/fff.jpg">
<img class=header src="https://dummyimage.com/50/00f/fff.jpg">
<br><br>
Rotate:
<br><br>
<img id=rotate src="">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. And much simpler as well!